# How to retrieve session data in service providers in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing a Laravel project. I am using Laravel 5.1. In my project, I am sharing data to all view in boot method of `appServiceProvider` in this way.

```
function boot()
{
    $items = $this->itemRepo->getItems(session("key"));
    view()->share('items', array('items'=>$items));
}
```

But session value is always null. I saw a lot of article online. But they were not working. How can I pass my session value to there ?

Answer (score 5):

I think your question answered in the following post **[Laravel 5 session data is not accessible in the app boot process](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-session-data-is-not-accessible-in-the-app-boot-process)**, You could use middleware like **Taylor Otwell** said in **[Add event for session started conversation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/7933)** *There is no session because there is no HTTP request*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it. I just created a new middleware called CommonMiddleware and just move my logic to middleware and share the data for all views in that middleware.

Comment: @WaiYanHein - Can you please post your answer? I need the same, thanks much!!

Comment: I disagree with the "should" part. I'd prefer "could". You may need to create routes according to the user's locale for example. I don't see how that can be accomplished with events or middlewares.

Answer (score 5):

This might be an old post but I got here while being stuck with the same problem, so let me post my solution here,just incase someone needs it.

```
    public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
    {
        $view->with('your_var', \Session::get('var') );    
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Service providers are executed before sessions are available, so you'll end up with empty session values if you try to use them there.
But the view composers are callbacks and are called when the view is rendered. Session are available at this time.

So you CAN use sessions in a service provider if it's in a callback that is executed later.

Just make sure any reference to sessions are done within the squiggle backets of the view composer and they will be available to the view. Do not pass in the  session to the view composer.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is a problem people are still facing, and I suppose it won't go away any soon, but unfortunately sometimes people seem to forget that Laravel is built upon PHP, and some things can be solved with simple and plain PHP.

In the case of this question, if you want to use session, I believe the request has already registered the session previously:

```
$items = $this->itemRepo->getItems(session("key"));
view()->share('items', array('items'=>$items));
```

Pay close attention!

This can be done by creating a Helper Function in a file like ***"app/helpers.php"***:

```
if(!function_exists('shared_items')) {
    function shared_items() 
    {
       return (new ItemRepo())->getItems(session('key'));
    }
}
```

If you don't know how to include file in Modern PHP development, this is how:

In **composer.json**:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       // definitions...
    },
    "files": [
       "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Then let Compose know you are not going crazy nor into tear:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

NOW instead of using a variable shared globally, you must use a function:

> shared_items();

That's it!

No magic, nor tricks... just plain old PHP along with Modern Best practices :D