# Using laravel policy Authorization in blade view file

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

I am trying to make authorization for users to some contents restrictions in view file, as i know that the only Authorization between laravel supported auth (gate,middleware) that can be used in view file is (policy) auth.
And policy auth is working by using laravel models, while my data sources is not model, i am just getting data from some webservices.

I created a new policy (isPlatinum)

```
    <?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\WebUser;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class isPlatinum
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function view(WebUser $user){
        return $user->user->subscription->type === 'platinum';
    }

}
```

Notice: the App\WebUser is not a model file , it's just a class that get user info from webservices.

In my blade view file

```
@cannot('view',$isPlatinum)
        This page is for Platinum Users
        @endcannot
```

giving error

```
Undefined variable: isPlatinum (View:
```

I know that i supposed to use Laravel Policy Auth only for models, in my situation, what is the right laravel auth i should use  and i can use is inside view file?

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass `isPlatinum` variable to view. You can [share data with all views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views):

Create a Service Provider as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // method to fetch the webUser?
        // $webUser = ;
        View::share('isPlatinum', $webUser->user->subscription->type === 'platinum');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , This is the way i think is best option for me , i did exactly what you mentioned , error showing response:
{"error":"token_not_provided"}, Token is provided for webservices request in App\WebUser , the token value is from Session::get('token') , The dd( Session::get('token')) is returning the token without any issue, i am just wondering if AuthServiceProvider is not working with Session values inside WebUser ?

Comment: Referring to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-session-data-is-not-accessible-in-the-app-boot-process , The provider boot method is fired after all providers register so session should work. in my case WebUser token value is stored in Session

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577946/how-to-retrieve-session-data-in-service-providers-in-laravel

Comment: you should add `view()->share()` in middleware instead of adding a Service Provider.