# Add Routes and Use Session Information in Service Provider

Tags: php, laravel

tl;dr; How can I get session data, then based on authentication, manipulate routes in a laravel ServiceProvider?

## The Problem

I need to do two things in a service provider. Register routes and use session data at the same time potentially.

## Existing Solutions

#### Route Without Session Data

I know `ServiceProvider::register` may happen before `RouteProvider::register` gets called. `ServiceProvider::boot` can add routes using something like this...

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    $router->prefix('api')->group(function ($router) {
        $router->resource('lists', '\App\Extensions\ExtensionName\Http\Controllers\MyController');
    });
}
```

Now this will add the route properly. But by the time that route is accessed, there will be no session data. Therefore `Auth::user()` will return `null`. And of course `Auth::user()` is going to return null in the `boot()` method as well during the adding of routes.

#### Session Data Without Route

I could extend the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` with my own middleware and fire an event like `session.started` at the end of an overloaded `startSession()` method. With this, I should have the session data needed to do something like `Auth::user()`.

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    Event::listen('session.started', function () use ($router) {
        if (Auth::user()->can('do.something')) {
            $router->middleware(['auth'])->prefix('api')->group(function ($router) {
                $router->resource('lists', '\App\Extensions\ExtensionName\Http\Controllers\MyController');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

However, the route will not be added at this point as that stage has already been long over with.

## Proper Solution Hints

I've been leaning towards registering my routes, then in my controller, I would somehow inject the session middleware so that it starts the session before my controller code actually runs. But I'm unsure how to do something like that.

It would be very nice if I could have access to the session data before even supplying my routes as it would be cleaner, faster and more secure to include routes that users have access to in the first place instead of checking on every call to them or removing them after they've been added and authorization has been checked.

## References

- [How to retrieve session data in service providers in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577946/how-to-retrieve-session-data-in-service-providers-in-laravel)
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-session-data-is-not-accessible-in-the-app-boot-process
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7906
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/7933
- https://laravel.io/forum/12-17-2014-session-content-not-available-in-service-providers-register
- https://josephsilber.com/posts/2017/01/23/getting-current-user-in-laravel-controller-constructor