# View Share doesn't return updated data, how then to share live data?

Tags: laravel

I currently have a model which access data like so:

```
$currentSessionID = session()->getId();
$displayCart = Cart::where('session_id', $currentSessionID)->get();
return view('layouts.cart')->with('cartDetails', $displayCart);
```

This model correctly retrieves the data in a current session.
To access this same data in a header file I'm using View::Share in the AppServiceProvider like so:

```
public funciton boot() 
{
      $currentSessionID = session()->getId();
        $inCartDetails = Cart::where('session_id', $currentSessionID)->get();
        View::share('inCartDetails', $inCartDetails);
}
```

In my blade the $inCartDetails returns empty.  I get [].
My suspicion is that this function ONLY gets called at boot.  Hence the name :) and that it's empty cause at the time of starting the session it's empty since user hasn't selected anything.  If this is correct how would I then pass live data to multiple views?

Comment: dump or log **$inCartDetails** in the `boot()` method and see if it contains data or not

Comment: $inCartDetails returns empty. I get []. @MohamedSabil83 . it has empty at beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is not available in the boot method of the service providers. You should create a middleware for this. Check out this answer here: [How to retrieve session data in service providers in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577946/how-to-retrieve-session-data-in-service-providers-in-laravel)